# Lowercasing and underscoring text in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, code-snippets

Hi I wondering how I could make a snippet in Sublime Text for doing this.

selected text:

```
Lorem Ipsum 200
```

result (in lowercase):

```
lorem_ipsum_200
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a [macro](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html). First, however, you'll need to install the [`Case Conversion`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Case%20Conversion) plugin via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net) in order to get the `convert_to_snake` command.

Open a new file in Sublime (use JSON syntax if you want) with the following contents:

```js
[
    {
        "command": "lower_case", "args": null
    },
    {
        "command": "convert_to_snake", "args": null
    }
]
```

Save the file in your `Packages/User` directory (`Packages` can be located by selecting ***`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`***) as `lower_snake.sublime-macro`.

Next, select ***`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`*** and add the following entry. If the file is empty, surround the keybinding with square brackets `[ ]`.

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+l"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/lower_snake.sublime-macro"} }
```

Save the file, highlight the text you want to modify, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to run the macro. You can change the keybinding to whatever you want, just make sure it doesn't conflict with anything else on your system.

Good luck!